# lavaan ERROR: ordered argument must be a character vector

Tags: r

I did an R function to print the beta weights from a fit object in lavaan:

```
psicomA <- function(model, bd, std.lv=T, ordered, estimator, ...){
#fit the model
fit <- lavaan(model = model, data=bd, std.lv = std.lv, ordered=ordered, estimator=estimator)
#Get std loadings
tablePesos<-parameterEstimates(fit, standardized=TRUE) %>%
    filter(op == "=~") %>%
    mutate(stars = ifelse(pvalue < .001, "***",
                          ifelse(pvalue < .01, "**",
                                 ifelse(pvalue < .05, "*", "")))) %>%
    select('Latent Factor'=lhs, Indicator=rhs, Beta=std.all, SE=se, Z=z, sig=stars)
 #format the table
   TabLoad <- kable(tablePesos,caption = "Factor Loadings for measurement model",booktabs = TRUE) %>%
    kable_styling(latex_options = c("striped","Hold_position"), font_size = 10)
#return the table
TabLoad
}
```

Then, I would call the function like this:

```
it <- c("BTF1","BTF2","BTF3","BTF4","BTF5","BTF6")
mBTF <- "BTF=~BTF1+BTF2+BTF3+BTF4+BTF5+BTF6"

psicomA(model=mBTF,  bd=bd[,it], std.lv = T,  ordered=T, estimator="DWLS")
```

It used to work fine... but, today I updated the lavaan version to the last one on CRAN and I get this error when running my function which I can't figure out why:

```
Error in lavaan(model = " BTF2~~BTF1\n BTF3~~BTF1 + BTF2\n BTF4~~BTF1 + BTF2 + BTF3\n BTF5~~BTF1 + BTF2 + BTF3 + BTF4\n BTF6~~BTF1 + BTF2 + BTF3 + BTF4 + BTF5\n", : lavaan ERROR: ordered argument must be a character vector
```

I tried with "ordered=it" but still get the same error. The error goes away if i used "ordered=F". I guess lavaan is not recognizing "ordered=T" as being the TRUE argument for the ordered setting when I pass it through the function... it used to work, so I wonder if there was some change in lavaan for working with ordinal variables?... Any ideas?

Thanks!